# Gerar xml através de uma classe, mesmo sem valor na propriedade

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou gerando um xml através de uma classe já existente, por exemplo

```
[XmlRoot("pessoa")]
public class pessoa
{
    //[CPFValidation]
    [XmlElement("cpf")]
    public virtual string cpf { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("nome")]
    public virtual string nome{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("telefone")]
    public virtual string telefone{ get; set; }
}
```

E estou usando o seguinte código para gerar o xml

```
        public static string CreateXML(Object obj)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false); 
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString(); 
        }
    }
```

Vendo que existe 3 propriedades: cpf, nome e telefone

Quando eu não atribuo valor a uma delas, fica null

Ao gerar o xml ele não gera o elemento

Eu gostaria que gerasse mesmo sendo vazio ou nulo

Se eu preencher
var teste = new Pessoa { 
cpf = "123",
nome = "fulano" }
e mandar gerar, ele gera apenas

```
    <cpf>123</cpf>
<nome>fulano</nome>


E não gera o elemento <telefone></telefone>
```

Então, eu utilizei uma anottation para setar os valores " " pra mim...srsrsrsrs

```
public class XMLAtributos : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            IList<PropertyInfo> propriedades = new List<PropertyInfo>(value.GetType().GetProperties());

            foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in propriedades)
            {
                object valor = propriedade.GetValue(value, null);
                if (valor == null)
                {
                    propriedade.SetValue(value, " " ,null);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amigo, veja a minha edição. Consegui resolver usando `ShouldSerialize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe que herda de Xml.XmlTextWriter e sobrescrever o método WriteEndElement, eu fiz isso num componente de NF-e, onde precisa ser criado o elemento inteiro.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class FullEndingXmlTextWritter
   Inherits Xml.XmlTextWriter

    Public Sub New(w As TextWriter)
        MyBase.New(w)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(w As IO.Stream, encoding As System.Text.Encoding)
        MyBase.New(w, encoding)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(fileName As String, encoding As System.Text.Encoding)
        MyBase.New(fileName, encoding)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub WriteEndElement()
        MyBase.WriteFullEndElement()  'Aqui está a mágica.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Na hora de serializar use essa classe:

```
serializer.Serialize(new FullEndingXmlTextWritter(), obj);
```

Comment: O meu é para o eSocial, rsrsrs, infelizmente acho que ainda não funcionou assim mesmo...

Comment: Funciona sim, na hora de serializar o método WriteEndElement deve ser chamado, coloca um breakpoint para ver se está sendo chamado.

Comment: Só se eu estou fazendo algo errado, pois aqui não funciona, rsrsrs

Answer (score 1):

Informe ao serializador que esse elemento pode ser serializado `null` (empty tag)

```
[XmlRoot("pessoa")]
public class pessoa
{
    //[CPFValidation]
    [XmlElement("cpf", IsNullable = true)]
    public virtual string cpf { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("nome", IsNullable = true)]
    public virtual string nome{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("telefone", IsNullable = true)]
    public virtual string telefone{ get; set; }
}
```

Se você descreveu certo seu problema isso deve resolver.

Existem mais parâmetros que podem ser passados para customizar sua serialização consulte a documentação [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Então, ele acaba ficando <telefone xsi:nil="true"
O mesmo funciona para classes? no XmlRoot? no caso se tivesse ali uma composição de uma classe

Comment: Fernando, assim como diz a doc, ele acaba ficando  xsi:nil, e eu gostaria que ficasse por ex: <telefone></telefone>

Comment: @Rod o suporte para serializar elementos 'null' desse class de maneira nativa que eu conheço é essa, mais não vejo muita razão para serializar um atributo 'null', a maior parte das APIs de deserialização trata que se o nó não é encontrado, é por que ele é 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve definir a propriedade a ser salva como uma string vazia `""`, ao invés de `null`. Assim o valor contendo a string vazia vai aparecer no xml.

**EDIT**

Tente criar os seguintes métodos na sua classe, juntamente com as suas propriedades:

```
public bool ShouldSerializecpf() {return true;}
public bool ShouldSerializenome() {return true;}
public bool ShouldSerializetelefone() {return true;}
```

Talvez isso resolva, mas não tenho certeza... vou testar e edito.

Mas ainda assim, devo realtar que caso funcione, quando carregar o valor do xml, o valor `null` possivelmente será trocado por uma string vazia.

**EDIT 2** Não funciona, mas é possível fazer funcionar com a **gambiarra** abaixo. =\

Faça a sua classe `pessoa` ficar assim:

```
[XmlRoot("pessoa")]
public class pessoa
{
    //[CPFValidation]
    [XmlElement("cpf")]
    public virtual string cpf { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("nome")]
    public virtual string nome { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("telefone")]
    public virtual string telefone { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializecpf()
    {
        this.cpf = this.cpf ?? "";
        return true;
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializenome()
    {
        this.nome = this.nome ?? "";
        return true;
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializetelefone()
    {
        this.telefone = this.telefone ?? "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Agora vai funcionar, mas isso não é algo muito legal de se fazer... afinal é uma gambiarra.

**EDIT 3** Não tem jeito de fazer de outra forma, que seja apenas usando o `XmlSerializer`... eu vi no código fonte, quando o valor é nulo, ele vai escrever `xsi:nil="true"` se IsNullable estiver definido... ou isso, ou nada.

Obviamente, que podemos fazer um pós-processamento no texto do xml gerado... poderiamos por exemplo usar uma regex, mas isso **não é muito recomendável, ainda mais para resolver um problema que parece não ter nenhuma implicação**:

```
xml = Regex.Replace(
    xml,
    @"<\s*([\w\-]*?(?:\s*\:\s*[\w\-]*?)?)\s*xsi\:nil\=""true""\s*/>",
    "<$1></$1>");
```

Ai você só teria adicionar `IsNullable = true` nos atributos `XmlElement` das suas propriedades, e logo depois de gerar o xml usar a substituição por regex.

Mas depois não vá reclamar se as pessoas te xingarem por estar usando regex com xml... hehe!

Comment: Isso é gambiarra amigo.

Comment: Então, são N classes, várias composições, várias propriedades, é muito estranho setar "" para todos

Comment: Isso é o comportamento padrão do xml. Não há como fazer de outra forma usando esse serializador. Se usar IsNullable, seu xml vai sair com o seguinte: `<cpf xsi:nil="true" />` ao invés de `<cpf></cpf>`. A não ser, claro, que isso seja aceitável.

Comment: Concordo com o @MiguelAngelo, null é diferente de "" e o padrão de dados XML trata essa diferença com o esse comportamento. Se o arquivo XML mostrar <telefone></telefone> é porque o atributo telefone é "" e não null.

Comment: Vish @MiguelAngelo, se eu tenho 100 propriedades, fazer isso para todas? fica muito trabalhoso, rsrsrsrs

Comment: Editei ai, com o que eu acho ser a última alternativa... já procurei no código fonte do XmlSerializer (especificamente o arquivo `XmlSerializationWriter.cs`) e não achei nenhuma opção para fazer isso.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo eu fiz uma annotation que percorre os elementos, e os que estiverem null, seta " ", rsrsrsrs até então, vou deixar assim...rsrsrs

Comment: @Rod Posta sua solução então... pode ser útil para outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. =)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca `XmlOutput`. Um XML escrito nela fica assim:

```
XmlOutput xo = new XmlOutput()
    .XmlDeclaration()
        .Node("root").Within()
            .Node("user").Within()
                .Node("username").InnerText("orca")
                .Node("realname").InnerText("Mark S. Rasmussen")
                .Node("description").InnerText("I'll handle any escaping (like < & > for example) needs automagically.")
                .Node("articles").Within()
                    .Node("article").Attribute("id", "25").InnerText("Handling DBNulls")
                    .Node("article").Attribute("id", "26").InnerText("Accessing my privates")
            .EndWithin()
            .Node("hobbies").Within()
                .Node("hobby").InnerText("Fishing")
                .Node("hobby").InnerText("Photography")
                .Node("hobby").InnerText("Work");
```

Introdução (em inglês): http://improve.dk/xmldocument-fluent-interface/

NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/XmlOutput/